# "Undefined method 'createToken'" in UserAuthController in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I'm trying to use passport in laravel and I'm following this tutorial: https://blog.logrocket.com/laravel-passport-a-tutorial-and-example-build/. But in step 4 I come across an error creating the UserAuthCotroller.

Here is my UserAuthController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class UserAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed'
        ]);

        $data['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);

        $user = User::create($data);

        $token = $user->createToken('API Token')->accessToken;

        return response([ 'user' => $user, 'token' => $token]);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'email|required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (!auth()->attempt($data)) {
            return response(['error_message' => 'Incorrect Details. 
            Please try again']);
        }

        $token = auth()->user()->createToken('API Token')->accessToken;

        return response(['user' => auth()->user(), 'token' => $token]);

    }
}
```

I have searched and some people say that I just have to add this lines to my user.php file:

```
use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
```

Here is my user.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Here is the error

```
[{
    "resource": "/c:/xampp/htdocs/application-example/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/UserAuthController.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
    "code": "1013",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined method 'createToken'.",
    "source": "intelephense",
    "startLineNumber": 40,
    "startColumn": 34,
    "endLineNumber": 40,
    "endColumn": 45
}]
```

Here is my config/auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
     
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that each reset token will be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

I have done that but still doesn`t work. Any idea?

Comment: Ah it doesn't work. Show the error in your laravel lock with the entire stacktrace, so from which gile the error came and which line. I quickly looked at your controller and I don't see "createToken" anywhere. Try yo paste that relevant piece of code in your question

Comment: could you post your User.php model?

Comment: @UnderDog I have updated the question with the error

Comment: @chuysbz I have posted the user.php model

Comment: So hopefully, hopefully I've got the right line: `$token = $user->createToken('API Token')->accessToken;`, it's strange, because you're creating a user right above that, but ok. In Laravel there's a function called dd(), it will tell you what's inside the variable. Right above that line 40 in your controller, do `dd($user);`, let's see the result in your original question

Comment: Before you do that, do a `dd($data);`, you're grabbing validated data from the request, let's see if $data is empty or null or whatever. After that, `dd($request);`

Comment: Could be a number of things, can you add your `config/auth.php` to the question for me and show me where `User.php` is located (`App\Models\User.php`)?

Comment: Did you also run install Passport using composer: `composer require laravel/passport`
And then do `php artisan passport:install`

Comment: @geertjanknapen I have posted the config/auth.php and User.php is located in App\Models\User.php. I used composer require and then php artisan passport

Comment: @UnderDog if I write thar line, it says "Undefined variable '$user'."

Comment: Everything seems correct, let's make sure `$user` is also correct in the register method.
Underneath the following line (`$user = User::create($data);`) put `dd($user);`
If it is the login method that you're testing, put `dd(auth()->user());` above this line: `$token = auth()->user()->createToken('API Token')->accessToken;`

Comment: And, once I have done that, what should I do next? @geertjanknapen

Comment: tell us what the output is